Why is header generation using `file_header_template` in editorconfig in Visual Studio 2022 ignored?
I have a project that I have been adding several class files. It's a pain to stop and add the standard header because I'm in thought about what I'm coding and don;t want to break the flow of thought.
Visual Studio has the abilty to generate a header by adding the .editorconfig file. I did so by right clicking on the solution in soultion explorer and clicking Add -> New EditorConfig. I then edited the file to add a simple header.
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]
file_header_template = Hello\nWorld\n 

#### Core EditorConfig Options ####

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
tab_width = 2
...

I then added a new class, positioned my cursor to the top of the file and hit <Ctrl>+.. I select Add file header. Instead of the header from .editorconfig I am offered a copy of the header on one of the other cs files in the folder. Not sure why it selects the one it does, it is not first alphabetically.
If I create a new project and try it with the default Class1.cs it does not give me the option to add the header. If I create a second file and add a header to either .cs file in the project, I add that header to the one without a header.
Is there another option some place that forces Visual Studio to ignore the .editorconfig header and use the autogenerated one? I'd like to take advantage of macros of the feature.
